# How to create collection in php 7?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to create collection in php 7 using mongodb?

I tried,

```
$collection = new CreateCollection($sessionid);
```

but it is giving me error as, **class CreateCollection not found**

Answer (score -2):

That's not how it's supposed to work. You should use the function [CreateCollection in the MongoDB class](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.createcollection.php).

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();
$db = new MongoDB($mongo, 'The name of your database');
$db->createCollection("sessionid");
```

Comment: Ans which is given by you it is work for php 5. my question is for PHP 7 (by PHongo technique).

Comment: Then there's no need to create the collection, just use it with `$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->yourdatabase->yourcollection;`